# How to get the last push date or file modification date when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, filesystems, heroku

What is the easiest way to get the latest file modification date (latest of all files, not a single one) or last push date to Heroku?

I would like to put on the footer: "Last site update on July 28, 2011"

Working in Rails 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the output of `git log`

```
git clone -o heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git
cd appname
git log
```

Comment: Can I run 'git log' from rails?

Comment: here is a grit gem https://rubygems.org/gems/grit, but I'm not sure you can use it from heroku